# symbol string concat in capistrano

Tags: ruby, capistrano

I'm running capistrano 3.

How can i get the below to behave correctly?

i'm expecting `cap deploy:test_symbols` to return "you are the man!"

```
  task :test_symbols do
    set :what, 'the man!'
    puts "you are #{:what}"

    # below causes error:
    # undefined local variable or method `what' for main:Object

    puts "you are #{what}"

  end
```

Comment: `puts "you are #{what}"` will do it for you ..

Comment: thats what i was expecting, but i get the error as mentioned above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you `set` a variable, you need to `fetch` it for use:

```
task :test_symbols do
  set :what, 'the man!'
  puts "you are #{fetch(:what)}"
end
```